# SelectMany() Cannot Infer Type Argument -- Why Not?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an `Employee` table and an `Office` table. These are joined in a many-to-many relationship via the `EmployeeOffices` table.

I'd like to get a list of all the offices a particular employee (`CurrentEmployee`) is associated with.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
foreach (var office in CurrentEmployee.EmployeeOffices.SelectMany(eo => eo.Office))
    ;
```

But this gives me the error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I understand I could add type arguments. But Intellisense recognizes that `eo.Office` is of type Office. So why isn't this clear to the compiler?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The type returned by the delegate you pass to `SelectMany` must be an `IEnumerable<TResult>`, but evidently, `Office` doesn't implement that interface. It looks like you've simply confused `SelectMany` for the simple `Select` method.

- [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) is for flattening multiple sets into a new set.
- [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) is for one-to-one mapping each element in a source set to a new set.

I think this is what you want:

```
foreach (var office in CurrentEmployee.EmployeeOffices.Select(eo => eo.Office))
```

Comment: Do'h! You're right. The `EmployeeOffices` <-> `Office` relationship is a one-to-one. I was confused by the many-to-many relationship overall. Thanks!